# django-pipeline not working with S3Boto3Storage

Tags: boto3, django-storage, django-pipeline, python-django-storages

How can I use S3Boto3Storage with django-pipeline?

According to the docs it looks like it would work:
https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storages.html#using-with-other-storages

The documentation looks a little bit outdated, because the package name and class name changed over the past years.

This is how my storage class looks like with the correct package and class name.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from pipeline.storage import PipelineMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class S3PipelineManifestStorage(PipelineMixin, ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    pass
```

In my settings.py I set the Storage class to the above created one.

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.storages.S3PipelineManifestStorage'
```

running collectstatic is returning this two errors

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 430, in _open
    f = S3Boto3StorageFile(name, mode, self)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.obj.load()
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 564, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticapm/instrumentation/packages/base.py", line 205, in call_if_sampling
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 915, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 128, in collect
    for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 30, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 98, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 116, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 72, in compress_css
    css = self.concatenate_and_rewrite(paths, output_filename, variant)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 136, in concatenate_and_rewrite
    content = self.read_text(path)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 219, in read_text
    content = self.read_bytes(path)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 213, in read_bytes
    file = staticfiles_storage.open(path)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 38, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/home/myproject/git/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 433, in _open
    raise FileNotFoundError('File does not exist: %s' % name)
FileNotFoundError: File does not exist: static/scss/adminmain.css
```

1. Any idea what is wrong?
2. Was someone able to use this combination succefully or is this feature broken in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

With the current master branch it works perfectly.

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline.git@c85a2572e53218716359126d9465cc63447817e5
```

There is a bug in the current 2.0.8 version. So wait for the next release.